# custom facebook fan page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page

I want a facebook fan page with something like this:

- With new design/theme, matching to my new website (orange/black)
- Custom Logo/contents display
- 30 boxes short description, on mouse hover, get some highlight for box and on click of specific box, opens a new pop-up
- pop-up should contain more detailed description and a link to specific page on my website

I think above things are achievable using `FBML` but any good ref/guide would be appreciated to help me quickly develop such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reference site where you find the full demonstration of custom FB fan page.

You can achieve that using `fb api`.

> http://www.kimwoodbridge.com/how-to-create-a-custom-facebook-fan-page/
>   http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/simple-steps-to-publish-on-facebook-fan-page-using-php/
>   http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2010/creating-a-custom-facebook-page/

Answer (score 1):

FBML is being deprecated by Facebook. You can create an iframe application instead. In an iframe you can basiclly do anything you like. As for themeing the page, you can't touch the facebook design. You can only control the contents of the iframe itself. You can however upload an image for the "profile picture".
Here is a guide for iframe apps for your reference:
http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/adding-iframe-application-to-facebook-fan-page/